# Issue with Palindrome class using Stacks

Tags: java, stack, palindrome

I am trying to write a Palindrome class using Stacks to determine if a word entered by user is a palindrome. There seems to be an issue in my Palindrome class. Can someone please help me identify it? My program works but no matter what word I type, it returns that the word is not a palindrome.

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class Palindrome
{
     public Palindrome()
     {
        Stack stack = new Stack();
        String input = "";
        boolean isPalindrome = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            stack.push(i);
        }

        String opposite = " ";
        while(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            opposite = opposite + stack.pop();
        }

        if(input.equals(opposite))
            isPalindrome = true;
        else
            isPalindrome  = false;
    }//end main   
}//end class Palindrome
```

Here is my PalindromeCheck class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PalinDromeCheck
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Palindrome pal = new Palindrome();
       Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);       //create scanner for  user to type a word

       String word = null;                          //initial word to check
       String stop = null;                          //stops processing of word

       do
       {
           System.out.println("Enter a word to determine if it is a palindrome: ");     
           word = type.nextLine();                  //user types word

           if(pal.equals(word))                 
               System.out.println("is a palindrome");
           else
               System.out.println("is not a palindrome\n");

           System.out.println("Would you like to try another word? Type Y for 'Yes' or N for 'No'");
           stop = type.nextLine();                  //stops processing
       }
       while(stop.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));           //continues to process and ignores upper or lowercase Y
   }
}
```

Comment: `pal.equals(word)` compares the two given objects. There is no way, you will get the correct answer. Please learn try to learn the basics of using a `class`, `constructor`, `methods` and then implement the logic. Your palindrome checking code is placed at a wrong place.

Comment: First your logic to check palindrome should not be in constructor rather you can make a static methodto check palindrome. Like @PrerakSola said for equals compare two object and since you have not overridden the equals metho, it is calling the equals of Object class which checks if the instance are same refereference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several bugs.

- First, you need to give the input to the Palindrome class.
- Second, when you reverse the input using stack, you push the index on the stack, not the character.
- Third, it's not a good practice to do everything une constructor. Palindrome class doesn't need to know the input as member or for initialization purpose

If you don't need to have several implementation of Palindrome, you shall use a static method.

Try this :

```
public class Palindrome
{
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String input)
     {

         char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();
         bool isOk = true;
         for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length/2 && isOk; i++){
             isOk &= inputArray[i] == inputArray[inputArray.length - i - 1];
         }
         return isOk;
     } // end method
} //end class Palindrome
```

Then, your main function could be :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a word to determine if it is a palindrome: ");     
    word = type.nextLine();                  //user types word

    if(Palindrome.isPalindrome(word)) {        
        System.out.println("is a palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println("is not a palindrome\n");
    }
} // End of main
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this your full Palindrome-Class? If yes, it has no input to handle!

```
public class Palindrome
{
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String input)
     {
        Stack stack = new Stack();

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            stack.push(input.charAt(i));
        }

        String opposite = "";
        while(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            opposite = opposite + stack.pop();
        }

        return input.equals(opposite);

    }//end main
}//end class Palindrome
```

this creates a static method you can use in your code like:

```
System.out.println("Enter a word to determine if it is a palindrome: ");     
word = type.nextLine();                  //user types word

if(Palindrome.isPalindrome(word))                 
    System.out.println("is a palindrome");
else
    System.out.println("is not a palindrome\n");
```

Comment: isPalindrome is not defined in your method, you could just `return input.equals(opposite);`

Comment: thx, i accidentally deleted the boolean o_O, at least did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Your input is empty because you set input to "" in the constructor. You would be better off using a constructor argument to contain the input and then keep track of that using a member variable.

The code you typed is probably better suited to be in a method (equals perhaps? You will have to override this). You might want to consider pushing the character from the input string onto the stack rather then 0, 1, 2, 3... n (where n = input.length() - 1).

Your current `.equals(word)` does not do what you think it does because you have not provided an overload.